# bypass json web token to do POST via broswer

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, http

In network tab I saw this on the request

[image]

Then I try to use https://www.hurl.it to try to post to the request. It failed. What is that authorization about? is that a security layer?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `JWT` token used for authentication purposes
You can read about it [here](https://jwt.io/)

Comment: Is that safe? I use it but I want to know user can bypass it or not.

Comment: Is that safe? I use it but I want to know user can bypass it or not. I use this with angularjs https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

Comment: it is probably passed on login and stored in localstorage/cookies and sent to server on every other request. It is analogous to cookies but are considered much safer . I don't think user can bypass it , Since it is evaluated in server side